# How can I make a switch buttons change the background of an Android Studio TextView?

Tags: android, background, textview, switch-statement

I would like to know how I can change the background-color of a TextView, through a switch button. It is necessary to clarify that my switch buttons are in MainActivy and my TextView are in other Activities, to which I access like this:

```
tvBoton = (TextView) findViewViewById(R.id.Schedule);
        tvBoton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, central.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                 }
            });
```

I don't know if it influences anything, but my switch buttons have SharePreferences:

```
pol = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch18);
        sharpol = getSharedPreferences("pol", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editorpol = sharpol.edit();
        pol.setChecked(sharpol.getBoolean(ex, false));
        pol.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean ispolChecked) {
                if (ispolChecked) {
                    editorpol.putBoolean(ex, true);
                    politica=(TextView) findViewViewById(R.id.polit);
                    politica.setText("Not working");
                } else {
                    editorpol.putBoolean(ex, false);
                }
                editorpol.commit();
            }
        });
```

As it is in the previous code, I tried inside the ispolChecked, in the true option, to reference the TetView, and then put setText, but this TextView, being inside another layout does not work. I also put setContentView(R.layout.main_activity) several times, but changing it to the respective layouts, but it didn't work either.

Honestly, I don't know what to do anymore. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: `I also put setContentView(R.layout.main_activity) several times` if you're doing this, you need to review what this function does and why you're using it, it should be some solid basics you have an understanding of and never have to wonder what it does

Comment: I use it to connect my java class with my xml, but I need to connect my java class with the others xml to use their TextView. Thank you for answer.

Comment: `tvBoton = (TextView) findViewViewById(R.id.Schedule);
        tvBoton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, central.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                 }
            });`.      please this code is in which activity ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreference` to store the state of the `Switch` and when you have stored it go to the next Activity and change background color of TextView based on the state of the SharePreference.